# How can I pin a TabBar when it is on scroll and the TabBarView can be swiped horizontally?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried a lot of ways to implement an interface like this using Flutter. But it didn't work as well as I wanted.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjXTH.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1oO7.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZqzT.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tkpVx.jpg)
I have tried [sticky_headers](https://pub.dev/packages/sticky_headers) and [flutter_sticky_header](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header) and both are not what I expected.

Comment: You might want to try a combination of a tabView and a pageView.

Comment: Did you try placing the Tabbar in the `bottom` parameter of a scaffold widget?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.